# Ethereum and traceability

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I'm trying to understand Solidity language in deep. I'm thinking in a traceability test project. But before start the first question appear in my mind. If I want to attach the production flow of one product specific on the blockchain. I have to make more than one contract in solidity? Or with just one contract i can do everything?

I mean imagine that we have a farm a carrier and finally a shop where the product is on sale. I have to generate one contract for each (farm,carrier, shop) and inside the contract insert a value that references to the previous actor? Or the way is to make all the product flow in the same contract??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that, but you don't need to deploy all your contracts since that would be costly and may create more problems in the future. You option here is to create those 3 contracts and import each of them into one contract (can be one of them or an other one)

The best is to think of contracts as executors, not just models and use `Struct` as your model base instead of a whole contract and implement struct related methods.

Comment: Thx for answering Kaki, I understand what you mean. But the struct part I can´t understand. Did you mean to make the Struct with the three imported contract??

Comment: I mean if I import 3 contracts to a "main" contract. Can I recovery the struct that I go generating in the time in each contract, and merge into the a generall struct of the main contract??

Comment: What I meant is that you can make a single contract with the state variables (used for storage) in a struct fashion and implement all methods relative to each struct in one contract. this instead of making each struct in a single contract and implementing its methods in that contract. it saves time and effort since you don't need to deploy each contract as independent and fully functioning.